# Inconsistency between packages adding appendices. Error: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: appendices

I'm using a .sty file provided by the university to write my thesis. If I try to add an appendix using a very simple case such as the file below (omiting nonrelevant data), I get the error *Missing number, treated as zero*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{a1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure that the problem comes from the following lines of the .sty file (if I comment them I don't get the error message, but I loose a good part of the formatting):

```
\makeatletter
\iffalse  % ancien template utilité par coralie
\definecolor{gris_chap}{gray}{0.85}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{20\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
     \if@mainmatter
       \raggedleft\scalebox{7}{\huge\bfseries\textsf{\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter~}}}  %\textsc{}

       \par\nobreak
       \vskip 30\p@

       \vspace{-3cm}

     \fi
   \fi
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \Huge \bfseries \textsf{ #1}\par\nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
 }}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{20\p@}%
 {\if@mainmatter
  \parindent \z@ \raggedleft
   \normalfont
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
   \vskip 30\p@
  \else
  \parindent \z@ \raggedright
   \normalfont
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
  \fi
 }}
\makeatother
\fi
% fin Alex chapitres

% nouveau templace chapitre
\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\position{\centering}
%% Note the difference between the commands the one is 
%% make and the other one is makes
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        {\HUGE  \scshape  \romannumeral \thechapter }
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

%% This uses makes

\iffalse
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        {\Huge \scshape \vphantom{\thechapter}}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\fi

% Pour avoir des pages réellement vides entre les chapitres
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother


% En-tête et pieds de page avec fancyhdr
\headheight=14.85pt
% pour récupérer les noms de section en minuscule
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\Makelowercase \markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%% End:
```

Does anyone know what is wrong within these lines? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you the first student that wants to include an appendix in the university's style file? :)

Comment: Indeed, most of us use other templates (which lead to other more complex bugs!)
I'm asking for the few colleagues of mine who used the template how they proceeded. =)